# How to add a middleware only on POST with Express and Node

Tags: node.js, express, post, router, middleware

I have a middleware that I want to be applied only when the http method is post.

The following works fine, but I get the feeling there is a better way:

```
'use strict'

const   express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router()


router.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        // do stuff
    }

    return next()
})

module.exports = router
```

I'd like to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
'use strict'

const   express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router()


router.post((req, res, next) => {
    // do stuff

    return next()
})

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `*` symbol:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

app.post('*', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('POST happen')
  next();
})

app.post('/foo', (req, res) => {
  res.send('foo');
});

app.post('/bar', (req, res) => {
  res.send('bar');
});

app.listen(11111);
```

This will respond with "foo" string on `POST /foo` and with "bar" string on `POST /bar` but always log "POST happen" to console.

Comment: `router.post('*', (req, res, next) => {
    // do stuff

    return next()
})` works